# angular 6 password validation not working

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular6

i am trying to validate below field. but error messages did not appear. please check my code. thanks

```
     <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" minlength="10" required [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':lgform.submitted && password.invalid}" name="password" id="inputPassword" #password="ngModel" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  [(ngModel)]="model.password">
            <div *ngIf="lgform.submitted && password.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
             <div *ngIf="password.errors['required']">Password is required</div>  
             <div *ngIf="password.errors['minlength']">minlength 10</div>  
          </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `<form #lgform="ngForm">` in your code.

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-password-validation-not-working?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

**component.html**

```
<form #lgform="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" minlength="10" required [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':lgform.submitted && password.invalid}"
            name="password" id="inputPassword" #password="ngModel" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
            [(ngModel)]="model.password">

        <div *ngIf="lgform.submitted && password.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="password.errors['required']">Password is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="password.errors['minlength']">minlength 10</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my library Easy Angular.

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ezng

And have a look at a StackBlitz demo on how easy form validation with it is.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8brst8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

None of the boilerplate code  is needed.

```
<ez-password minlength="10" required>Password</ez-password>
```

Is all you need.

Comment: found the solution..
<div class="help-block login-val"  *ngIf="password.hasError('pattern') && password.dirty"> Password should be  8 characters, at least one letter and one number</div>

Comment: Please add the relevant code from your links to this answer.